# How do i get Azure build pipeline data into a local installation of Elasticsearch

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I have Elasticsearch, logstash, Kibana and filebeat installed on my local machine.
I would like to pull in the data from our Azure DevOps automation build pipeline.  E.g. We have a Cypress Automation Build Pipeline in Azure DevOps which runs our automation tests and I would like to use Elasticsearch to query the results, show the total number of tests run, number of passed and failed tests and build the Kibana visualization graph.

How do I configure the filebeat.yml file to pull the Azure logs in using a local intallation or Elasticsearch?
From filebeat.yml the input paths section I see it wants a path to the log file.
From Azure Devops, from our build pipeline if I download the logs and save them to my local and then I upload the logs from my localhost Kibana http://localhost:5601/ From Ingest Node Pipelines i selected Upload a file and then select the index pattern
I see some data.
This is not the correct way as I would have to download the logs manually each day.

How would I configure the filebeat.yml to pull in the logs from Azure.
Can it not be done using a local installation of Elasticsearch?

Any help, guidance much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using local files, use Filebeat's [Azure Module](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.12/filebeat-module-azure.html).

Comment: To use the Azure module I would have to export the logs to the Event Hub using Azure Portal.  To create an Event hub in Azure there is a pricing tier.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-create  Can it not be done without paying fees?  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-module-azure.html  Thanks

Comment: In that case, I don't think Filebeat can help you. You'll need some kind of automation to deliver the logs. Whether you write a script or use a workflow manager like Apache Airflow, you'll need to put the log files somewhere Filebeat can get at them. Hope that helps